# View Java Unicode in Windows 7

Tags: java, unicode, windows-7

I'm working on a Java program that attempts to output certain Unicode characters (for example, U+2660 through U+2663). Working in Windows 7, under no circumstances can I successfully view these symbols. Contexts I've tried:

- In my jGRASP IDE.
- In a Windows command prompt.
- By printing to a text file.

Is there any way at all to successfully view these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real way to do this on Windows. Using Linux is the easiest solution.

The Windows console sort-of supports UTF-8 and Java sort-of supports changing the encoding. So you can do this:

In the Windows console, use the *Properties* context menu to set the font to Lucida Console (which can display a lot of Unicode characters), then:

- `chcp 65001`
- `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MyProgram`

When I do this on Windows 7, the last two characters of each *print* or *println* are repeated, but otherwise it seems to work.

Note that this will also change the default encoding for file I/O in your program to UTF-8.

Edit: I just noticed your third category "printing to a text file". Yes, open the text file for writing in UTF-8 (or any encoding that supports Unicode). Then, view it in an editor (you may need to specify the encoding when opening if there is no BOM and it is not the system default encoding - you can do this with "File" > "Open" in jGRASP) and view using a font that can display the characters.