# how can i print ⛀ from java with cmd.exe?

Tags: java, cmd, unicode, encoding

I need to print on cmd ⛀ this character. Its encoding in UNICODE is U+26C0.
I tried with this:
System.out.print("⛀");
but in running I get "?" character
Thanks.

Comment: The output device needs to properly interpret and support Unicode characters.

Comment: If I understood correctly your problem is not related to java, it's about how you would get `cmd` to print such symbols.

Comment: For what it's worth, on my Mac Chrome doesn't show your symbol in this question, and in my Java console the symbol doesn't appear either, even though other unicode works just fine. Maybe it's just an oddball one with limited support? It's a shame though, because it (and the related symbols) seem perfect for a text-based draughts game, which I assume is what you're making.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47740439/1831987 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11927518/1831987.  The short answer is the `chcp 65001` command, but if you search Stack Overflow for that command, you’ll see that it is not a perfect solution.  Windows does a poor job of supporting Unicode on the front end, despite most OS functions being natively UTF-16.

Comment: A rare glyph… It's rendered correctly **either** in  _Command Prompt_ pane of [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/), **or** in pure `cmd.exe` using _NSimSun_ font (or _MS Gothic_ font).

Comment: @VGR Yes, `chcp 65001` from the command line is a prerequisite, but you must also use a font in the Command Prompt window which can render that character. Based on another comment above, I used _NSimSun_, and the character was displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Not a programming problem. Obtain and install a font containing a glyph for that particular character.

## A rare glyph

For a character to appear, the computer must have a font containing a [glyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) for that particular code point number as defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). No font comes even close to having glyphs for all of the 143,859 characters defined in Unicode. Any font has only a small subset of those.

Your particular character, U+26C0 WHITE DRAUGHTS MAN, seems to be a rarity. This despite being defined in Unicode so long ago.

My Apple iPad running the latest iPadOS in Safari does not display a glyph for that character on [this page](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/26C0.html) nor [this page](https://codepoints.net/U+26C0).

Nor does it appear when running [this code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/1wU7M2).

```java
        String whiteDraughtsMan = "\u26C0" ;
        System.out.println( whiteDraughtsMan ) ;
```

You will need to obtain and bundle/install a font containing a glyph for that particular character. You could create your own font with your own glyph designs. You could purchase a font through any of several vendors. If none found, you could petition or commission any commercial vendor or open-source font project to add such glyphs to one of their products.